# How Mobile number validation varies with the URL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

I have written mobile number validation script as you can see in below.the problem it is working fine with the URL1.but not with the URL2.I want to know why is that?

URL1 -   http://axbc.com/con/s2.php

URL2 -   http://axbc.com/con/s2.php?key=d908e8401774411861043

Here is my Code

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{

    $mobilenumber = $_POST['mobilenumber'];
    if(!empty($dialogmobilenumber)) // phone number is not empty
    {
        if(preg_match('/^947\d{8}$/',$mobilenumber)) // phone number is valid
        {
            echo 'success';

        }
        else // phone number is not valid
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Mobile Number is Not valid.. Format should be ');

                 </script>";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you POST to URL2 ?

Comment: @sonique actually it is random number which i am get from using GET

Comment: since you are accessing your variable using $_POST, you never get after line 2. Maybe you should move the else code, at the end of your script, not sure what is the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

*Your code is working fine for me in both urls.
It is doing, what it is meant for, It is matching all the 11 digit numbers starting from '947'+8 nos.*

As, you are not using the passed variable anywhere in this piece of code,So it can never be the cause of your error.

One thing,You are receiving mobilenumber as POST in `$mobilenumber` variable.
So,why are you using `$dialogmobilenumber` to check if it is empty or not ?
Have you defined this anywhere in the program.

```
if(!empty($dialogmobilenumber)) // phone number is not empty
    { ...
```

Another thing, Is your form also present in `s2.php` ?
If not, what is your action contains `(action="?")` for the form ?

> Note: If you can paste the complete code and output that you are getting for
>    URL2, that will be good.